# openCV imshow in WSL using Xming

Tags: opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, xming

I am working on some video processing tasks and have been using opencv-python 4.2.0 as my go-to library. At first there was a problem with displaying video frames using the `imshow` function - I would only see a small black window, but I thought there was something wrong with my logic. I tried reproducing the problem in its simplest form - loading and displaying a static image:

```py
import cv2
frame = imread("path/to/some/image.png")
print(frame.shape)
cv2.imshow('test', frame)
```

The output:

`>>> (600, 600, 3)`

[image: opencv window]

I have not had similar problems in this development environment before. I am developing under WSL (Ubuntu 16.04) and use Xming to display the program's window under Win10.

Comment: I'm surprised it shows at all without `waitKey()`

Comment: if you don't use `waitKey()` then it has no time to display it. `imshow()` doesn't wait for image and program ends work.

Comment: Found any solution? I'm having this problem as wel

Comment: @Snail the solution proposed by furas solves the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image in window is updated when function `waitKey()` is executed - so you have to use it

```
import cv2

frame = cv2.imread("path/to/some/image.png")
print(frame.shape)

cv2.imshow('test', frame)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

At least it resolves this problem on Linux Mint 19.3 based on Ubuntu 18.04